# LocalReport error in a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, winforms, localreport

I’ve an error with a Winforms LocalReport in a ClickOnce application. The rdlc report works fine in debug mode. However, once the application is compiled and deployed using ClickOnce, it generates the following error:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing.

 ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'C:\Users\Pestl\Desktop\Reports\SSR.rdlc' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: 

An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: error BC31519: 'C:\Users\Pestl\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\88XNZ2OP.YPJ\PDYZJK8H.P65\rlim..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_94e6df98390d1e62\rLIMS.exe' cannot be referenced because it is not a valid assembly.

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings()
at rLIMS.ExtensionMethods.LocalReportExtensions.Print(LocalReport report)
at rLIMS.Models.Submission.PrintSSR(Int32 projectID, Int32 submissionID)
```

To be honest, I don’t even understand the error. Maybe that would help me search for a solution. My first thought was that ClickOnce applications only have access to limited locations such as the Data folder, but moving the reports to different spots did not help. Not sure where to go from here. Again, it works fine in debug mode.

Updated to include the calling code.

> ```
>     DataController.AddParameter("submissionID", submissionID);
>     DataTable dtSubmission = DataController.GetDataTable(sqlSubmission);
>
>     DataController.AddParameter("submissionID", submissionID);
>     DataTable dtSample = DataController.GetDataTable(sqlSample);
>
>     ReportDataSource sourceSubmission = new("dsSubmission", dtSubmission);
>     ReportDataSource sourceSample = new("dsSample", dtSample);
>
>     //get path and print
>     string? rdlcPath = Project.GetRdlcPath(projectID);
>     if (rdlcPath != "" && rdlcPath != null)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             ReportViewer reportViewer = new();
>             reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sourceSubmission);
>             reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(sourceSample);
>             reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(rdlcPath, "SSR.rdlc");
>             reportViewer.LocalReport.Print();
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>
>             throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
>         }
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         throw new Exception("The report file path is not defined for the project. Please define in:\n\n" +
>                             "Project  Manage  Settings  File paths");
>     }
> ```

Comment: how are you referencing your rdlc in the code? I dont think we can debug anything if you do not show code